# How to disable transition if there are words in a search bar?

Tags: html, css

I have a search bar that has a transition animation applied to it.

Initially the bar looks like this:
[image: search bar, initial]

On hover, it transitions to look like this:
[image]

The issue starts here. When I hover away from the text/bar, the bar transitions back to the initial bar. When hovered back, any text written is still there. I want it to be such that the transition is disabled when the bar is active. (So that, the user still sees the text despite hovering away from the bar.)

Below is the CSS for the search bar:

```css
/* search */

.search-box {
  background: #2f3640;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-txt {
  width: 240px;
  padding: 0 6px;
}

.search-box:hover>.search-btn {
  background: #5b9cdd;
  color: #2f3640;
}

.search-btn {
  float: right;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  border-radius: 60%;
  background: #2f3640;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 0.2s;
  color: #5b9cdd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-btn>i {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  line-height: 20px;
  width: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!-- search section of the header -->
<div class="search-box">
  <input type="text" name="" class="search-txt" placeholder="What are you searching for?" />
  <a class="search-btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: You might need to use some js, would be easier to solve if you can add your HTML code

Comment: Changes made. You can find the html code for the search bar above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add javascript. You can add the following css and it should do the job:

```
input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    width: 240px;
}
```